# Adding tabbed "list" in Magento Modern theme

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to emulate the list view that Magento does by default in the "Additional Information" tab:

[image: Default layout]

I have created the `\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Downloads.php` file needed to pull the info for the tab:

```
<?php
 class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Downloads extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
 {
    protected $_list;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/downloads.phtml');
    }

    public function getChildHtmlList()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_list)) {
            $this->_list = array();
            foreach ($this->getSortedChildren() as $name) {
                $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($name);
                if (!$block) {
                    Mage::exception(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Invalid block: %s.', $name));
                }
                $this->_list[] = $block->toHtml();
            }
        }
        return $this->_list;
    }
}
```

I have also created the template file to display the info in `\app\design\frontend\default\themename\template\catalog\product\view\downloads.phtml`:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getChildHtmlList() as $_html): ?>
    <?php echo $_html ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And added the XML to the `catalogue.xml` file:

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>downloads</alias><title>Downloads</title><block>catalog/product_view_downloads</block><template>catalog/product/view/downloads.phtml</template></action>
```

This SHOULD give me a "Downloads" tab with a list view in it the same as the "Additional Information" tab but alas, it doesn't.

How do I tell Magento where to pull the information from - I have set up my attributes in the back end, they are in a group called "Downloads" in the attribute set so it should work.

Thanks,
Myles

Comment: Well, I see quite a few things wrong: 1. First of all, don't create files in the core; 2. Second, the path to the Downloads.php file (in Mage\Catalogue) is different than the class name (Mage_Catalog); 3. The templates should be in the theme's template folder themename\template\catalog; 4. if you added the tab block to the correct place in the layout xml file (catalog.xml), then most probably the name mismatches are the problem

Comment: Hi David, the only instructions I could find all repeated the same thing - add the class file into core. 1) Where should it be instead?
2) Sorry that is my UK english kicking in, they are infact all Catalog - I have amended my question. 3) Same thing here, lapse in my concentration, the path is infact `\themename\template\catalog`. 4) I have added it in the right section (if I enable dev template highlighting it appears in the right place).

Comment: 1. Should be in a custom module 4. In the modern theme for 1.6, the action should be declared inside the block with name="product.info.tabs" <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >

Comment: You should never touch core files. Adding as many tabs to product list is easy enough. Here are some links you can  try http://ken.edmonds-commerce.co.uk/magento/add-review-tab-in-magento-product-page/ and http://www.woolleydesign.net/2012/07/magento-adding-tabs-to-your-product-pages/